# Linq casting between types

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

Is there a better way to cast this list of guid strings to guids using linq:

```
public static IList<Guid> ToGuidList(this IList<string> guids)
    {
        IList<Guid> guidList = new List<Guid>();
        foreach(var item in guids)
        {
            guidList.Add(new Guid(item));
        }
        return guidList;
    }
```

I looked at:

```
guids.Cast<Guid>().ToList()
```

but that didn't seem to be the trick.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: By the way, just to clarify - LINQ is only going to do the *exact* same thing you wrote in your code above... so the word "better" can only mean "fewer lines of 'my source-code'". It won't be faster or different, but it would 'look' cleaner.

Comment: the q should have read " how to do this using linq"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
guids.Select(x => new Guid(x)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
guids.Cast<Guid>().ToList()
```

Just attempts to cast each element of the list to a `Guid`. Since you can't directly cast a string to a `Guid`, this fails.

However, it's easy to construct a Guid from a string, you can do so for each element in the list using a selector:

```
var guidsAsGuid = guids.Select(x => new Guid(x)).ToList()
```

Comment: I think you missed the parenthesis in your Cast() call

Answer (score 1):

You just can use the .Select to implement a proper cast:

```
var guids = from stringGuid in dataSource
            select new Guid(stringGuid)
```

or

```
IList<string> guidsAsString = ...
var guids  = guidsAsString.Select(g=>new Guid(g));
```

Comment: Too much WOW for you? It's `Guid`, not `Guild`  ;p

Comment: Oups, =D. Fixed it. No I've never played WoW.